# How to speed up stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Below given is my procedure takes too much time to execute.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE rank1 BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE id1 BIGINT;
    DECLARE rankskip BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE mark DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE oldmark DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT -100000;
    DECLARE done int DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE cursor_i CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 
            (rightmarks - negativemarks) as mark, id 
        FROM 
            testresult 
        WHERE 
            testid = testid1 
        ORDER BY 
            (rightmarks - negativemarks) DESC;  

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
    OPEN cursor_i;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_i INTO mark, id1;
        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

        IF oldmark = mark THEN
        BEGIN
            IF IsRankSkip = 1 THEN
            BEGIN
                SET rankskip = rankskip + 1;
            END;
            END IF;
        END;
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET rank1 = rank1 + rankskip + 1;
            SET rankskip = 0;
        END;
        END IF;

        SET oldmark = mark;
        UPDATE testresult SET rank = rank1 WHERE id=id1;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cursor_i;
END
```

This loop iterate minimum 2000 times.

Here IsRankSkip and testid1 is an argument passed to the procedure.

This procedure takes 65.343152046204 time to execute. If anybody guide me how can I reduce executing time?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Most probably you don't need a stored procedure. Please explain what you are trying to do. Provide sample data and show create table output

Comment: Sorry cannot. At least not until you provide the additional information requested for in my first comment.

Comment: I will try to explain you complete flow.
I have table with resulttrigger name. when data is insert in this table trigger is fire  which update student rank in their table. that trigger contains 2 procedures which one of the above I was given.  
could you tell me please when trigger is fired at that time php code wait for a while until trigger complete it's work and after code execution is start OR after trigger fire php code and trigger both works as parallel?

Comment: your answer is most important for me ... thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single `update` statement, making use of variables that change during the execution of it:

```
UPDATE testresult a
JOIN   (    SELECT  id,
                    @row := @row + 1 row_number,
                    @rank := if(mark = @lastmark, @rank, @row) as rank,
                    @dense_rank := @dense_rank + if(mark = @lastmark, 0, 1) as dense_rank,
                    @lastmark := mark as mark        
            FROM    (   SELECT   rightmarks - negativemarks as mark,
                                 id 
                        FROM     testresult
                        WHERE    testid = testid1
                        ORDER BY 1 DESC
                    ) data,
                    (SELECT @row := 0, @dense_rank := 0) r
       ) b
    ON a.id = b.id
SET    a.rank = if(IsRankSkip, b.rank, b.dense_rank);
```

The query with alias `b` calculates the rank and adds it as a column in the result set. In fact, it adds three kinds of numbers:

- `@row`: the sequential row number without special treatment of equal values
- `@rank`: the same as row number of the value differs from the previous value, otherwise it is the same as in the previous row
- `@dense_rank`: this increments when the value differs from the previous value, otherwise it is the same as in the previous row

You can choose which one to update your *rank* column with. In the above SQL I have used the two procedure variables *IsRankSkip* and *testid1*.

#### Remark

If you are always calling your procedure for all *testid* values, then the above can be further improved, so all these updates are done with only one `update` statement.